# Get data from SPList with a key value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I´m starting with Sharepoint 2010 development with Visual Studio and I´ve been the entire evening looking for a solution to retrieve data from a list according with the value of one of its fields.

I´m looking for something like

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemWithValue("Field_Name");
```

What I´m trying to achieve is convert a SPList into a html list with a TreeView format.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `CAML` query.

```
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.Query= " <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Field_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>Field_Value</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection items = mylist.GetItems(oQuery);
```